# How do I create a window on a cover page with specific dimensions in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to create a title page for my thesis. One of the requirements is this:

"Your title page should have the title, author and date arranged to appear in the window on the cover, as shown. The dimensions for the window are: 100mm horizontal by 60mm vertical, centered starting 70 mm down from the top of the cover."

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a text box.

Comment: @Johnathan, I think enabling the ruler if you haven't already done so (under the View tab) would help as well.